# Implementing sliding realtime 2D plot in Qt

Tags: qt, plot, qimage, qwt, qcustomplot

I am getting streaming measurement data from an ultrasonic device moving inside a pipeline, and I want to make a sliding/realtime plot of these measurements. The Y axis would represent a gradient of the 360 degrees around the pipe, and the X axis would represent the length-wise position in millimeters. In other words, the X axis will update and move at the same rate as the scanner while new data is arriving (approx 40Hz). The value at each (x,y) coordinate represents one measurement, which should be mapped to a color in a colormap.

I am new to graphics (systems&backend guy) and I have been looking at QImage, QWT and QCustomPlot but none of them seem to straight-forward solve the problem without having to manually build a 2D matrix, draw it in a QImage, and update and shift the coordinates of each datapoint and redraw to move/scroll it. QCustomplot does this very nicely for graphs, but I don't see how it can be applied to their colormaps.

Any hints to frameworks or packages that provide primitives (or widgets) for this kind of plot would be much welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Qwt.  The trick is creating a wrapper around the series data that triggers a replot every time you add a data point.  If you want to get fancy you can add a timer that removes old data from the series and triggers another replot.

See the CPU, oscilloscope, and realtime examples that come with the Qwt source code.  They implement this trick.

Comment: Thanks! Trying this out and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I actually found Qwt quite difficult to use, but I have implemented using a basic QPainter to paint a matrix of QPixmaps which is then shifted when new items are added, and redrawn on paintEvents.